# How can a scroll a specific row or section to the top of a Xamarin.Forms.ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `Xamarin.Forms.ListView` that contains events that are grouped by date. There are events that occur in future and events that occur in the past.

Users would like to have their screen load with a future event closest to the current date in view so that they do not need to manually scroll down to view it.

What options do I have with a `Xamarin.Forms.ListView` to accomplish this for iOS and Android users?

[image: Screenshot of Current Initial View]

Comment: I would guess that there may not yet be support for scroll-to-item yet in the Xamarin.Forms API. That's not a definitive answer, but from the exploration I've done of the API so far, that seems like something for a future release. Don't quote me on that.

Comment: How do you get the right angle bracket button on each row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made some progress. I am able to accomplish my goal in iOS by creating a CustomListView and an iOS render to support it.

In Xamarin.Forms you create a CustomListView then after you have loaded the list you an call `ScrollToRow(item,section)` to manually scroll to the row you need.

In iOS the renderer maps the method to `UITableView` message `ScrollToRow(...);`

For Android I still need to create the renderer but I do know that I need to map to the calls `getListView().setSelection(...);` or `getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(...);`

I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this but for now it is getting the job done

**Source For:** `Common.CustomListView`

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Common {
    public class CustomListView : ListView {

        public Action<int, int, bool> ScrollToRowDelegate { get; set; }

        public void ScrollToRow(int itemIndex, int sectionIndex = 0, bool animated = false) {
            if (ScrollToRowDelegate != null) {
                ScrollToRowDelegate (itemIndex, sectionIndex, animated);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS Renderer Source:**`YourApplication.iOS.Renderers.CustomListViewRenderer`

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using Common;

using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;

using YourApplication.iOS.Renderers;

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(CustomListView), typeof(CustomListViewRenderer))]
namespace YourApplication.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class CustomListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnModelSet (VisualElement view) {
            base.OnModelSet (view);
            var listView = view as CustomListView;
            listView.ScrollToRowDelegate = (itemIndex, sectionIndex, animated) => {
                ScrollToRow(itemIndex, sectionIndex, animated);
            };
        }

        private void ScrollToRow(int itemIndex, int sectionIndex, bool animated) {
            var tableView = this.Control as UITableView;
            var indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection (itemIndex, sectionIndex);
            tableView.ScrollToRow (indexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I wondered, it there is a quick & dirty approach using the `SelectedItem` property. See here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666776/why-cant-i-set-the-selecteditem-property-of-xamarin-forms-listview)