# :Why can't I set the SelectedItem property of Xamarin.Forms.ListView?

Tags: xamarin.forms

```cs
object lastItem = null;
foreach (object item in listView.ItemsSource)
    lastItem = item;
if (lastItem != null)
    listView.SelectedItem = lastItem;
```

But all I got was a 'Sequence contains no matching element' exception when setting the `SelectedItem` to the desired lastItem. How can this be, as I have grabbed lastItem from the `ItemsSource`?

Edit: Context added... ListView XAML and a Model representing the values as distinct text files in IsoStore (yes, I know, Settings would be a better choice)

XAML:

```xml
<ListView Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="listView" IsVisible="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="5">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Datum, StringFormat='{0:d}'}" />
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding KmBeginn}" />
                                <Label Text="-" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding KmEnde}" />
                                <Label Text=" (" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Entfernung}" />
                                <Label Text=" )" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Kategorie}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Reisezweck}" VerticalOptions="Fill" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

C#:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EasyRideTouch.Models
{
    public class Eintrag : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string FilePrefix { get; set; }

        public Eintrag(string prefix = "")
        {
            FilePrefix = prefix;
        }

        public DateTime Datum
        {
            get { 
                string datestring = ReadStringFromIsoStore();
                if (datestring == "")
                    return DateTime.Today;
                else
                    return new DateTime(Int32.Parse(datestring.Substring(0, 4)), Int32.Parse(datestring.Substring(4, 2)), Int32.Parse(datestring.Substring(6, 2)));
            }
            set {
                string datestring = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", value);
                if (datestring != ReadStringFromIsoStore()) 
                {
                    WriteStringToIsoStore(datestring); 
                    OnPropertyChanged(); 
                } 
            }
        }

         public string Kategorie
        {
            get { return ReadStringFromIsoStore(); }
            set { if (value != ReadStringFromIsoStore()) { WriteStringToIsoStore(value); OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        }

        public string KmBeginn
        {
            get { return ReadStringFromIsoStore(); }
            set { if (value != ReadStringFromIsoStore()) { WriteStringToIsoStore(value); OnPropertyChanged(); OnPropertyChanged("Entfernung"); } }
        }

        public string KmEnde
        {
            get { return ReadStringFromIsoStore(); }
            set { if (value != ReadStringFromIsoStore()) { WriteStringToIsoStore(value); OnPropertyChanged(); OnPropertyChanged("Entfernung"); } }
        }

        public string Entfernung
        {
            get
            {
                if (KmEnde == "" || KmBeginn == "")
                    return "";
                else
                {
                    int ende;
                    int beginn;
                    try
                    {
                        ende = Int32.Parse(KmEnde);
                        beginn = Int32.Parse(KmBeginn);
                    }
                    catch 
                    {
                        return "";
                    }
                    int entfernung = ende - beginn;
                    if (entfernung < 0)
                        return "";
                    else
                        return entfernung.ToString() + "km";
                }
            }
        }

        public string Reisezweck
        {
            get { return ReadStringFromIsoStore(); }
            set { if (value != ReadStringFromIsoStore()) { WriteStringToIsoStore(value); OnPropertyChanged(); } }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private string ReadStringFromIsoStore()
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (isoStore.FileExists(GetPropertyName()))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(GetPropertyName(), FileMode.Open, isoStore))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
                    {
                        return reader.ReadToEnd(); 
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                return "";
        }

        private void WriteStringToIsoStore(string value)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(GetPropertyName(), FileMode.OpenOrCreate|(isoStore.FileExists(GetPropertyName()) ? FileMode.Truncate : 0), isoStore))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(value);
                }
            }
        }

        string GetPropertyName()
        {
            StackTrace callStackTrace = new StackTrace();
            StackFrame propertyFrame = callStackTrace.GetFrame(2); // 2: below GetPropertyName frame
            string properyAccessorName = propertyFrame.GetMethod().Name;

            return FilePrefix + (properyAccessorName.Replace("get_","").Replace("set_",""));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code snippet works for me. I suspect the issue elsewhere, and you'll have to share some more context.

Comment: @Stephane Delcroix: done